# Why do spirits marry humans?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah

Why do spirits mentioned in the Talmud agree to marry humans? There are stories that non human spirits marry humans and have kids with them, this is also mentioned in genesis, a Midrash seems to say Cain was born from union with the Satan as well.

Comment: It's not a marriage.

Comment: In general it is helpful to add specific sources to your claims so people can help you find better answers